# Creating new NSStrings for each item in a plist array

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, plist

I am attempting to create a class that takes each item in a Plist array and assigns them to an NSString for use in other classes in the program. Here's what I have so far:

```
NSString *appBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *plist = [appBundlePath stringByAppendingString:@"/Contents/Resources/Values.plist"];

plistArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plist];

for (NSString* plistItem in plistArray) {
    finalPlistString = plistItem;
}

NSLog(finalPlistString);
```

This code goes and finds the plist within the app bundle, assigns the contents of the plist to an NSArray and uses a for loop to set the plistItem NSString to the items in the plist array. Then the resulting string is logged using NSLog. It logs the last item in the plistArray, which makes sense because there is only one NSString variable to assign to.

How can I create a new NSString for each item in the plist array? If you are wondering, plistArray and finalPlistString are defined in the .h file.

Comment: Not getting what you want to achieve??

Comment: I want to take each string value in the plist and assign them to an NSString so I can use the strings elsewhere in the program.

Comment: Why not use plistArray itself elsewhere in the program?  It already contains all the string values.

Comment: The values in plistArray already *are* NSStrings (unless the plist contains more complex entities).  And assigning them to *one* NSString makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the easiest way to get he path for a plist from a bundle is

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Values" ofType:@"plist"];
```

Second, after you read in the array, you now have all the strings in the array for further use in your program. So it takes you two lines of code to get all the data.

To access, say, the third item in the array, just use

```
plistArray[2]
```

-- there is nothing else you have to do, i.e. you do not even need a variable. E.g. to assign to a label you write

```
label.text = plistArray[2];
```

Your for loop below that does not make sense. To get the last item of an array, it is easier to do this:

```
NSString *lastItem = plistArray.lastObject;
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize I didn't have to assign the value to an NSString and that I could use them directly. This solution is simple and is what I wanted.